# SQL Server 2005 replication triggers - how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to run the replication of one table in SQL Server 2005. Replication should be one way. From 1 master server to many children servers.

I thougt about snapshot replication, but I don't want to schedule it only for example every hour/minute ect. (I know how to do this.) but **ALSO** triggered it evry time new data appears in master server's table.

Is there a way to do it? Which type of replication should I use and how to configure it?

Comment: just reduce the replication schedule to 15 seconds say...

Comment: And what is the impact to performance of SQL Servers? Is it not to often?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use transactional replication?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176%28SQL.90%29.aspx